Methods to Solve for Areas of circles in complex Problem
I was at my school's Math Club messing around with combinations of circles and squares to see what simple problems I could come up with until I came across this problem. I posed it to the club and not one of us(a number of us had been to and won math olympiads and other national competitions) could solve it or even come close. I continued to work on the problem for two days before solving it and showing it to my school's Math department who also were unable to solve it.
Here is the problem: Given a Circle with a radius of 1 unit. There are four smaller congruent circles inscribed within that larger circle, each smaller circle is tangent to two of the other smaller circles and touching the larger circle at one point. Solve the Area of one of the Smaller Circles.
Here is a Visual Version of the Problem: 5-Circles Graph.
My Questions are:

Can You solve it?
What method could be used to solve it?

Edit

In essence the question is asking for the radius of the smaller inscribed circles, from which the area can then be calculated. The large circle has radius 1 as stated in the original question.

It seems to be similar but from my interpretation I don't believe it answered my Question.  To rephrase what I'm asking, I looking for methods to solve this problem, as the solution I found seemed clunky and indirect.

For this question, radius of large circle = 2 times radius of medium circle + radius of small circle. You really only need to know the ratio of the radii.

Can you solve the area of one of the smaller circles then? Though this is similar to how I solved the problem.

Ratio of areas is square of the ratio of radii.

As with many geometry problems, there may be different solutions. Here is what I have found:
Construct points A, B, C, D as shown:

Then we can show $|AC|=r+\sqrt{2r^2}$
But this is the radius of the larger circle so $r+\sqrt{2}r=1$ and therefore $r=\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt 2}$
This means the area of each small circle is $\pi \times \left(\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt 2}\right)^2=(3-2\sqrt{2})\pi$.
